# Confidence intervals in the wrong place on a lattice barchart

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I am want to create a bar chart of the following data with confidence intervals:

```
IVs <- expand.grid(fault=c("L", "H"), moral=c("L", "N","H"),     verdict=c("Not Guilty", "Guilty"))
freq<-c( 8, 24, 12, 41, 4, 11, 32, 17, 79, 65, 42, 23)
(  Question2 <- data.frame(IVs, freq=freq)  )
```

I have used a logistic regression model to calculate the probability of a guilty verdict in each condition and I've used lsmeans to calculate the CIs of these probabilities.

```
library(lsmeans)

m3.lr<-glm(verdict ~ fault * moral, data=Question2, family=binomial, weights=freq)
(  m3.lr.lsm <- lsmeans(m3.lr, ~fault*moral, type="response")  )
```

I then want to use this to create a bar chart of this data.  I have used variations on this code to create other bar charts in this data set and it has worked fine.  However, now that I want to use the code to create a bar chart of all six conditions, the CIs appear in the wrong place.  The CIs lines are appearing in the middle of each moral character group, even though it is that they each belong on a separate bar.  I can't seem to work out how to move the CIs lines to their individual bar.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code I used to create the graph is:

```
library(latticeExtra)

barchart(prob ~ moral, groups=fault, data=summary(m3.lr.lsm), 
     ylim=c(-0.05,1.05), xlab="Moral Character", ylab="Probability Guilty") + 
 layer(panel.key(c("green=Low Victim Fault", "pink=High Victim Fault"), 
              corner=c(0, 1), lines=FALSE, points=FALSE)) +
 layer(with(summary(m3.lr.lsm), panel.arrows(moral, asymp.LCL, moral, asymp.UCL, ends="both", angle=90, length=0.1)))
```

This is my current graph with the CIs lines in the wrong place.

[image]

Comment: It's ggplot, not lattice, so I'm commenting rather than answering: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(summary(m3.lr.lsm), aes(x = moral, y=prob, fill=fault)) +geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(1)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), position = position_dodge(1), width = 0.2)`

Comment: Thank you!  I happy to use ggplot instead of lattice, so that's perfect.

Comment: no problem, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that lattice is having trouble figuring out that you have subgroups in your bar plots. It's difficult to fix in lattice - Here's a gpplot fix, using `position_dodge`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(summary(m3.lr.lsm), aes(x = moral, y = prob, fill = fault)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.2)
```

[image]